# How do I cover the entire page with 3 images?

Tags: html, css

I want to cover my entire page with 3 images but I can't seem to figure out how make them cover the bottom of the screen while still being responsive.

This is how I want it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfXCo.jpg (while still being responsive)

```
<style>

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height: 100%;
}

</style>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div id="box">
    <img src="1.jpg" />
    <img src="2.jpg" />
    <img src="3.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zkcjg51f/

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: I've tried to fix this by myself for over three hours. It's 1 a.m, my head is hurting and I barely know what I have and what I haven't tried anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like full height, responsive images, use the images as background-images and then size the container as you need.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.img-div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.img-frodo {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/9bYOn81.jpg');
}

.img-hp {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/pwG5Bch.png');
}

.img-avatar {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/KZ96Xsx.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-div img-frodo"></div>
    <div class="img-div img-hp"></div>
    <div class="img-div img-avatar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much!